# Haskell counterpart of list of abstract class objects in OOP

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm learning Haskell and come across this question. **Without using existential types**, how do we translate the following OOP pseudocode into Haskell? Not the way to simluate the OOP concept in Haskell, but the proper Haskell way to do it.

```
class MetricQuery { ... }

abstract class Metric[T] {
  def computeValue(q: MetricQuery): T
}

class LinkClicksMetric extends Metric[Int] { ... }
class ButtonClicksMetric extends Metric[Int] { ... }
class PostCommentsMetric extends Metric[Int] { ... }
...

query: MetricQuery = ...
metrics: List[Metric[Int]] = ...
results: List[Int] = metrics.map(\x -> x.computeValue(query))
```

One of my idea is that instead of using a typeclass, we simply make the `computeValue` function a field of the Haskell datatype:

```
data MetricQuery = ...

data Metric a = Metric {
  computeValue :: MetricQuery -> a
}

linkClicksMetric :: Metric Int
linkClicksMetric = Metric { computeValue = \q -> ... }

buttonClicksMetric :: Metric Int
buttonClicksMetric = Metric { computeValue = \q -> ... }

results =
  let query = ...
      metrics = ...
   in fmap (\x -> computeValue x query) metrics
```

I think this could work, just not sure whether this is a "proper" Haskell way to do it.

Also, I don't know how I can store additional data (i.e. member variables in OO terms) with a specific metric. I tried to parameterize the metric type constructor with a state type, but that leads to different specific metric types (e.g. `Metric Int State1` vs. `Metric Int State1`). One idea is to make a `data MetricState = ... | ... | ...` and make `state :: MetricState` a field of `Metric` so every specific metric can define its own state type.

Comment: What is an object with a single method in Java would be just a function in Haskell.

Comment: @n.m. What about the state it might carry? What about objects with more than one methods?

Comment: Haskell has partial function application, so e.g. `f = (+) 5` defines a function `f` of one argument that carries a state inside (a single value of 5). When applied to an argument, say `f x`, it returns `5 + x`. (`(+)` is a function of *two* arguments).

Comment: As for several methods, the easiest way to represent such an object is just a record of functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Metric` data type would probably be better as just a type synonym.

```
Metric a = MetricQuery -> a
```

If your specific metrics carry other information then one way you can get this is by partial application:

```
buttonClicksMetric :: Button -> Metric Int
buttonClicksMetric button query = ....
```

This works because by substitution of the type synonym you can read the type as

```
buttonClicksMetric :: Button -> MetricQuery -> Int
```

So now you can create a `Metric Int`  by passing a `Button` to `buttonClicksMetric`. Likewise you could create another `Metric Int` with `linkClicksMetric` and put them both in a list.

But what if you want to do other things with a `buttonClicksMetric` which need access to the button, such as showing it. Then you need a data type instead (this design pattern is often called "reification" of the function:

```
newtype ButtonClicksMetric = ButtonClicksMetric {getButton :: Button}
```

(Aside: `newtype` works almost exactly like `data`, except that you can only have one field and one constructor, and it has zero runtime cost. There are some subtle differences in the semantics for bottom values that you don't need to worry about here. If you needed more fields in ButtonClicksMetric then you would use `data`.)

The type of `buttonClicksMetric` now becomes

```
buttonClicksMetric :: ButtonClicksMetric -> Metric Int
```

Everything else works just the same.

Comment: Furthermore, closures and objects are both *already* examples of existential types, just baked into the language. With a closure, you’re hiding the captured values (like a `Button`) and presenting an interface that has a function type like `MetricQuery -> Int`; with an object, you’re hiding the object’s fields (and concrete type) and presenting an interface that has some method signatures like `computeValue(q: MetricQuery): Int`. That is, a closure is isomorphic to an object with one method, so you can represent an object of one method quite straightforwardly with a closure, like this.